# ScreenRecorder: how to use createScreenCaptureIntent() in a Service or IntentService?

Tags: java, android, capacitor

I am trying to implement a ScreenRecoder app using Ionic Capacitor Framework and implementing a Plugin to be able to use native code to be able to achieve the task.

I am taking as a reference this project: https://github.com/yrom/ScreenRecorder

There everything is implemented into an Activity component, but I don't want to use native UI, so I can not use the Activity as in the project and integrate it in Capacitor Plugin.

I have tried to implement the basic recording functionality into a Service, but I failed. The biggest issue I found is, how I can run next lines of code from a Service:

```
private void requestMediaProjection() {
        Intent captureIntent = mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
        startActivityForResult(captureIntent, REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
    }
```

That part requires the onActivityResult to deal with it, right?

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION) {
            // NOTE: Should pass this result data into a Service to run ScreenRecorder.
            // The following codes are merely exemplary.

            MediaProjection mediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
            if (mediaProjection == null) {
                Log.e("@@", "media projection is null");
                return;
            }

            mMediaProjection = mediaProjection;
            mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mProjectionCallback, new Handler());
            startCapturing(mediaProjection);
        }
    }
```

So the request to initialize the MediaProjection can be achieved and continue with the next step, startCapturing method, so the device screen will be recorded.

Does anybody know how to do that from a Service, IntentService or any other way avoiding to implement native UI and being able to deal with the startActivityForResult required(at least I think so) to continue the codeflow after the captureIntent?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "so I can not use the Activity as in the project" -- you do not have a choice. "how I can run next lines of code from a Service" -- you can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can't to `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` in a Service, you needed Acitivity.

Once you got successfull `resultCode` in `onActivityResult()` you can send that `resultIntent` to a `Service`. Then in service you can create and start the `mediaProjection`

Try to create a **Transparent** **Activity** and do `startActivityForResult()` call. In `onActivityResult()` check if `resultCode` is OK or not, if it's OK you can send `resultIntent` to a service, then initialize and start `mediaProjection` there.

After all this `finish()` that transparent activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ProjectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_MEDIA_PROJECTION = 4578;

    public static void requestProjectionIntentActivity(Context ctx) {
        Intent pIntent = new Intent(ctx, ProjectionActivity.class);
        pIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        ctx.startActivity(pIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MediaProjectionManager mgr = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        startActivityForResult(mgr.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_MEDIA_PROJECTION: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //send screen capture intent (data) to service
                }
                else {
                    //FAIL
                }
                finishAndRemoveTask();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with some OS, like MiUi. You need to check special permission in settings to be able to start activity from background, othervise nothing will happen.